# Ubuntu 17.10 disable background application blurring effects

Tags: gnome, themes, effects

Currently on Ubuntu 17.10 whenever an application is considered not in focus, it becomes grayed out like so:

[image]

I would like to disable this effect because I have multiple monitors and everything that isn't in focus becomes grayed out and difficult to read.

Is there a simple way to disable this effect?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with Ubuntu 17.10, instead is related to the theme "United-Ubuntu" you're using. Change the the to default or any other theme, which doesn't have this feature or bug.

For example, you can use default "Ambiance" theme.

Here is a screenshot of my current Minwaita-OSX theme. You can see that there is no blurring

[image: my theme scshot]